# SSRS 2005: can't insert hyperlink

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a SSRS 2005 report and I would like to use one of the column to be `hyperlink`.

I set the field to display the `Parent Number`, which is `=Fields!Parent_Num.Value`
And at the `Navigation` tab, I selected `Jump to URL` and I have this, `="Form_View.aspx?id=" + CStr(Fields!ID.Value)`

My problem is, the column is not clickable. It displays the Parent_Num correctly, but it's not `blue color` or `clickable`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `+` to `&` in your `URL` string

```
="Form_View.aspx?id=" & CStr(Fields!ID.Value)
```

SSRS by default doesn't add the colour for hyperlink you need to modify the colour in the `font` section